# Error when trying to inherit from base class: cannot override stored property

Tags: swift

What am I doing wrong here?

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int = 0
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}


class Circle: NamedShape{
    var radius: Double

    // Here it says:"Cannot override with a stored property ‘name':
    var name: String

    init(radius: Double, name: String) {
        self.radius = radius
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    func area(radius: Double) ->Double{
        var area: Double = radius * radius * 3.14
        return area
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {

        // Here it says that 'name' is ambiguous:
        return "A circle by the name of \(name)with the area of \(area(radius))"
    }
}

let test = Circle(radius:5.1,name: myCircle)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert in Swift, but it looks like you are defining another property of a subclass (Circle) which happens to be called the same name as a property in its superclass (NamedShape).

The whole idea of your `NamedShape` seems to be it should be the class storing the name. So why don't you skip the property `name` in the subclass? I mean, **delete the line where your first error is**.

And don't worry. You will still be able to refer to `name` in subclass. That's the whole point of defining `Circle` to extend `NamedShape`.

Comment: Also define `myCircle` to avoid a syntax error there.